# Export MS Access queries to notepad

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to export all the queries (names with query code) to a notepad/word document. I'm not good at VBA code but I found this code from some site in web which exports all the queries with query code into a notepad. code:

```
Sub ExportQueries()
Dim db As Object
Dim qdf As Object
Dim ff As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
ff = FreeFile()

Open "C:\Queries.txt" For Output As #ff

    For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs

        Print #ff, "Query: " & qdf.Name & vbCrLf
        Print #ff, "SQL:" & vbCrLf
        Print #ff, qdf.SQL & vbCrLf

    Next qdf

Close #ff
End Sub
```

But I want to export only those queries in the Macro that I'm using.
How to extract queries used in a specific Macro? Can someone give me the code plz?

```
My Macros - Alerts_MCR
            EBAC_MCR
```

there are few more macros also that I'm using.

Comment: "Can someone give me the code plz?" - you've come to the wrong place....

Comment: how come? i wanted to learn how to hardcode a macro in the above code

Comment: so start writing some code....

Comment: I don't know VBA. but i'm made to work on it.

Comment: Then I suggest you start with a basic VBA tutorial...

Comment: that's a very good idea but my manager won't wait till i learn the code and write it by myself.. so i'm seeking some help here..

Comment: It's not reasonable for your manager to expect you to be able to do something you have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically do what you describe in a robust way is definitely a non-trivial exercise. The resulting VBA code would have to :

- take your list of Macros,
- inspect each action of each macro to see if it invokes a query, either directly (e.g., via `OpenQuery`) or indirectly (e.g., by doing a `RunCode` that calls a VBA function which itself invokes a query),
- parse any queries that are invoked to see if *they* invoke any other queries, again either directly (via a `FROM` clause) or indirectly (e.g., via a VBA function), and do that recursively, and
- also check to see if the macros call any *other* macros and, if so, do the same thing with them.

All of this makes for a very interesting development project, but (IMO) is well beyond the scope of the Stack Overflow Q+A format.